# Traceroute doesn't work on Linux, on Windows it does

Tags: traceroute

I'm a Linux Mint user. I've run traceroute on Linux and tracert on Windows. On Linux, I just get asterisks. Everything seems to work fine on Windows. Here are the outputs

Windows:

[image: Windows]

Linux Mint:

[image: Linux Mint]

Why is this happening and is there something I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: And you can access the Internet from the Linux Mint system?  Are these OSes both running on the same PC?  As a dual-boot or using virtualization?

Comment: Down voting because of same reason as @depquid comment. This question lacks many critical information to solve this.

Comment: I don't think he deserved any downvotes for this. There was enough information here to provide an answer.

Comment: I'm not looking for upvotes, just for answers, so I won't defend myself :) Of couse I can access the Internet, this seems to me a trivial question. Sorry for not writing about the machine: yes, it's the same (with dual-boot)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A likely reason for the difference is that by default Window's `tracert` uses ICMP, whereas Linux `traceroute` defaults to UDP. Using the `-I` option for traceroute should produce the same results as `tracert`:

```
traceroute -w 10 -I google.it
```

From the `traceroute` documentation:

> In the modern network environment the traditional traceroute methods can not be always applicable, because of widespread use of
>   firewalls.  Such firewalls filter the "unlikely" UDP ports, or even
>   ICMP echoes.  To solve this,
>   some  additional tracerouting methods are implemented (including tcp), see LIST OF AVAILABLE METHODS below. Such methods try
>   to use particular protocol and source/destination port, in order to
>   bypass firewalls (to be seen by
>          firewalls just as a start of allowed type of a network session).
>
> ### LIST OF AVAILABLE METHODS
>
> In general, a particular traceroute method may have to be chosen by -M name, but most of the methods have their simple cmdline
>   switches (you can see them after the method name, if present).
>
> #### default
>
> The traditional, ancient method of tracerouting. Used by default.
>
> Probe packets are udp datagrams with so-called "unlikely" destination ports.  The "unlikely" port of the first probe is 33434,
>   then for each next probe it is incremented by one. Since the ports are
>   expected to be unused, the
>          destination host normally returns "icmp unreach port" as a final response.  (Nobody knows what happens when some application
>   listens for such ports, though).

Comment: This does not work for me. Gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
traceroute -M icmp google.it
```

Comment: It would be much better if you could [edit] your question and explain what this does, and why it would solve the issue described.

Comment: ICMP is never the good tool to troubleshoot networking problems (and you could as well just use `ping` then, no need for `traceroute -M`). If you try to assess HTTP connectivity (which I guess based on the name used in the question) then you need to do an HTTP query which a TCP/80 or TCP/443 typically. Hence you use `tpctraceroute` for that.